# Average age of top five European football leagues?

Tags: football, trivia, statistics

*Toulouse* *France* team with average age of *23.91* was the *youngest team on pitch for domestic league 2016-17*. Some article claimed *Germany* had the most number of team with the lowest average age.  But I'm interested in knowing,

What was the average age of top five European football leagues for domestic league 2016-2017?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a ranking done by [CIES Football Observatory](http://www.football-observatory.com/-Rankings-) manually calculating the result is as follows:

> France Ligue 1: 24.1805 years
>
> Spain La Liga: 24.2455 years
>
> Germany Bundesliga: 24.968 years
>
> Italy Serie A: 27.3375 years
>
> England Priemier League: 27.857 years

I will **recalculate** again to verify. But this result shows France **Ligue 1** was the league with lowest average on the pitch among Top 5 leagues for 2016/17.

Data table used for calculation [[Source]](http://www.football-observatory.com/IMG/sites/rk/young/en/):

Picture of the table is obtained from *CIES Football Observatory*.

[image: ranking 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]
[image: 4]
[image: 5]
[image: 6]